# In jOOq, why is the connection highly coupled with the statement construction?

Tags: java, performance, jooq

Let's say I have a query builder

```
ResultQuery query = DSL.select().from(TABLE);
```

and a connection/context pool

```
DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.MYSQL)
```

I want be able to :

- reuse the same query object for different connection/context
- if the same query instance can't be use, use the query as a template
- execute the query build task outside of the query execution process

Since the query object in jOOQ has a configuration with the connection:

Does this mean that a query should only be build on an active connection context?

disclaimer: I'm using jOOQ from some weeks now, maybe I'm just missing some docs.

---

For instance, the next code is not thread safe and it won't be safe unless it gets sync over the query.

```
ctx.fetch(query).map(mapper);
```

source DefaultDSLContext.fetch at 2157 version 3.5.3

```
public <R extends Record> Result<R> fetch(ResultQuery<R> query) {
    final Configuration previous = Utils.getConfiguration(query);

    try {
        query.attach(configuration());
        return query.fetch();
    }
    finally {
        query.attach(previous);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> reuse the same query object for different connection/context

You shouldn't do that with jOOQ 3.x. There are a variety of historic reasons why (some) jOOQ `QueryParts` are mutable. This will change - hopefully - in jOOQ 4.0. Background info here:

- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/dsl-and-non-dsl (section about mutability)
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2198

> if the same query instance can't be use, use the query as a template

What you can always do is implement AST construction functions, that produce new `QueryParts` on-the-fly, e.g.:

```
public static Condition template(...) {
    Condition result = DSL.trueCondition();

    if (...)
        result = result.and(...);

    return result;
}
```

This obviously also works for complete queries.